# Why does jQuery templates add double quotes to some strings

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, jquery-templates, double-quotes

**Background**

I'm working with jQuery templates, ASP.Net MVC Razor views and Twitter.

**Problem**

Using jQuery templates with some strings automatically results in those strings being wrapped in "

**Details**

I created a jQuery template that looks like this:

```
<script id="twitterResultsTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
        <div class="tweetItem">
            <div class="userAvatar"><img src="${profile_image_url}" alt="${from_user} Image" /></div>
            <div class="tweetSummary">
                <div class="bd">before ${text.parseUserName().parseHashTag()} after</div>
                <div>${created_at}</div>
                <div class="ft">${prettyDate(created_at)}</div>
            </div>
        </div>        
        <br style="clear: both;" />
</script>
```

The following javascript formats the username and hash tags

```
String.prototype.parseUsername = function () {
    return this.replace(/[@]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+/g, function (u) {
        var username = u.replace("@", "")
        return u.link("http://twitter.com/" + username);
    });
};

String.prototype.parseHashtag = function () {
    return this.replace(/[#]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+/g, function (t) {
        var tag = t.replace("#", "%23")
        return t.link("http://search.twitter.com/search?q=" + tag);
    });
};
```

Unfortunately, what's happening is that the text is being wrapped inside double-quotes. So,

**What I expect to get is:**

```
<div>before @user Hello World #hello #world after</div>
```

**Instead, what I get is:**

```
<div>"before @user Hello World #hello #world after"</div>
```

Why are double quotes automatically being inserted? More importantly, how do I prevent it or fix it?

**UPDATE**

I have determined that this only happens when `@` is included in the text . . . which happens any time a username is included.

**SOLUTION**

I'm not exactly sure why this solution works, but it does. I'll update this post later as I get a better understanding of the problem.

Change (doesn't work)

```
<div class="bd">before ${text.parseUserName().parseHashTag()} after</div>
```

To: (works)

```
<div class="bd">before {{html text.parseUserName().parseHashTag()}} after</div>
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the effect. Check http://jsfiddle.net/FloydPink/gRxyC/1/embedded/result/ - Can you post more details on the versions you use and also your code?

Comment: Actually, you can see the effect right on your site: http://jsfiddle.net/c5H3A/2/

Comment: "My handsome darling Tony Bennett's album DUETS II is #1! So happy! Here's The Video for our song THE LADY IS A TRAMP: http://t.co/v9bXj5QH"    -- it appears with quotes

Comment: When inspecting it using Google's developer tools, all the text inside the li elements are wrapped in quotes.

Comment: No such problems with Firefox, so I beleive it is something to do with the way Chrome handles the JSON. Besides, even in Chrome, it renders without the quotes, isn't it?

Comment: You don't "see" the quotes in Chrome, but they're in the markup. The problem is that I'm doing a replace on username and the tags. So the final markup is "<div>"before <a href='http://twitter.com/user'>@user</a> Hello World <a href='http://twitter.com/%23hello'>#Hello</a> after </div>

Comment: With the quotes there, any the user and tag hyperlinks render as markup, instead of how they should.

Comment: The problem was occurring in all browsers, including FF. Firebug did not show the double quotes, but the result was the same: Firefox was rendering the raw <a href =" . . . rather than displaying it as html. I have updated the post with the fix.

Comment: Glad that you figured it out. Why don't you post that as an answer and mark it as one? :)

Comment: Thanks. I just added it. SO makes you wait for 2 days, however, before marking your own answer as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why this solution works, but it does. I'll update this post later as I get a better understanding of the problem.

Change (doesn't work)

```
<div class="bd">before ${text.parseUserName().parseHashTag()} after</div>
```

To: (works)

```
<div class="bd">before {{html text.parseUserName().parseHashTag()}} after</div>
```